# binding the data to custom child directives which are exist in the parent derictives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This program gives the output only for `parent-directive`.
What can I do to show `child-directive` directives?

This is my program

```
<div ng-app="Myapp">
  <parent-directive>
    <!--parent directive -->
    <child-directive>
      <!--child directive -->
    </child-directive>
  </parent-directive>
</div>
```

this is angularjs code for creating parent directive and child direcives functions

```
var app = angular.module("Myapp", []);
app.directive("parentDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<p>Hello this is parent directive</p>",

  };

});
app.directive("childDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<p>Hello this is child directive</p>",
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does not work because the template of your parent directive overrides the html you have declared between `<parent-directive></parent-directive>`. To avoid this you have to allow transclusion in the parent directive:

```
app.directive("parentDirective",function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    transclude: true,
    template:"<p>Hello this is parent directive</p><div ng-transclude></div>"
  };
});
```

The child directive is then inserted wherever you declare **ng-transclude** in the template of your parent directive.
A very good explanation of this can be found here: 
https://thinkster.io/egghead/transclusion-basics